# Extract image Path from Wiki XML Syntax

Tags: php, regex

i try to parse the Wikipedia XML which i get from  the xml [wikipedia export](http://de.wikipedia.org/wiki/Spezial:Exportieren/)

In one case i need to extract all image path. The raw markup looks like,

```
  [[Bild:nameOfImage.png|image description]]
```

"Bild" can also be "Image", "File" or "Datei"

To extract the text for an Image i use this regex.

```
'|\[\[.*\|.*\]\]|U'
```

This works fine, if in the image description isn't an other '[[ .. ]]', like

```
[[Bild:nameOfImage.png|image Description with a [[new wiki link]] ]]
```

My question is, how can i modify the Regex to get **all** text between the first "[[" and the **last** "]]" without to count all '[' an ']' character.

thanks in advance

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Since you're using PHP, you're probably able to use [recursive patterns](http://php.net/manual/en/regexp.reference.recursive.php).
Considering you're not capturing anything:

```
/\[\[(((?>[^\[\]])|(?R))*)\]\]/U
```

Note that I haven't tried this regex since I have no way to use PHP.

**Edit:**

```
preg_match('/\[\[(?>[^\[\]]|(?R))*\]\]/U', '[[Bild:nameOfImage.png|image Description with a [[new wiki link]] ]]', $array);
var_dump($array);
```

seems to work.